# Как в angular применить стили для дочерних компонентов, но при этом не вынося их на уровень всего приложения?

Tags: css, angular

У меня есть дочерние компоненты в родтельском и я хочу применить стили родительского к дочерним, но при этом не выводя стили на уровень всего приложения, а сделать только для дочерних, тоесть без ViewEncapsulation на высший уровень.
Как такое реализовать?
Сейчас я пока что придумал только написать базовый файл стилей и пишу css import в стилях дочерних компонентах.

Answer (score 1):

**:host-context()**

Использовать `:host-context()` в стилях дочернего компонента.

Пример:

```
:host-context(parent-css-selector) {
 ...some styles
}
```

Comment: Советую не использовать `ng-deep`, так как он находится в статусе `deprecated`, а значит скоро перестанет поддерживаться. [ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: @"Nikolya Shirshov" спасибо. Я вот только так и не понял - ::ng-deep   устарел или нет? много статей пишут, что он устарел, но альтернативы я не нашёл нормальной, кроме как ViewEncapsulation.none поставить, чего не хотелось бы.

Comment: @"Sergey Glazirin" а какая альтернатива вместо него? я что-то ищу и не могу найти